# alloc initWithObjects vs arrayWithObject

Tags: iphone, ios

I don't understand why if I write these code

```
icons = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
             @"appointment",
             @"work",
             @"anniversary",
             @"me",
             nil];
```

the app crashed. But then I replaced by these code

```
icons = [NSArray alloc] arrayWithObjects:
             @"appointment",
             @"work",
             @"anniversary",
             @"me",
             nil];
```

and the app did't crash. 
But there is the same affect between these methods !
I don't know why ? Can u help me ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155097/ipad-large-nsarray-initwithobjects-vs-arraywithobjects

Comment: provide some more code and crash logs.

Comment: Plz check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6744468/what-is-the-difference-between-arraywithobjects-and-initwithobjects

Comment: These methods differ by memory management. Second code gives you an autoreleased object, and if it works, you probably missed a `retain` call somewhere.
We'd need more code to be sure, of course.

Comment: "you probably missed a retain call somewhere". I think you want to say  release" instead of retain ? Yeah thank you

Answer (score 1):

1. initWithObjects method means you have to release the object of array whenever this is not required as this is instance method and for more details [click](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/initWithObjects%3a):
2. arrayWithObjects method means you don't need to release the object of array whenever this is not required as this is class method and for more details [click](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/initWithObjects%3a):

If you are not clear with the points so revert me..

Comment: Thank u. I forgot release :P