# NSArray losing values when I put self into it

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, nsarray, nsdictionary

So I have this piece of code:

```
- (void) connectSelector:(NSArray *)args {
NSError* error;
NSString* data = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[args objectAtIndex:0]] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];

NSLog(@"%@", data);

NSDictionary* dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"connector", @"data", @"error", nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:self, data, error, nil]];

[[args objectAtIndex:1] performSelector:@selector(dataDownloaderDidDownloadData:) withObject:dictionary];
}
```

The values NSArray in dictionary is losing its 'self' value. Why is this so?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you using `self` as a key in the dictionary?

Comment: Are you sure you don't have your objects and keys arrays backwards? Normally you want the keys to be some simple, copyable value (like your strings "connector", "data", etc.).

Comment: I think you can use only instance of those classes which classes conforms to `NSCopying` protocol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you've got the keys and values element back-to-front.  You probably meant:

```
NSDictionary* dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:self, data, error, nil] forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"connector", @"data", @"error", nil] ];
```

Or to use modern syntax:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = @{ @"connector" : self, @"data" : data, @"error" : error };
```

(Not every object can be used as a key in a dictionary).

Comment: I got this when using the modern syntax: `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[2]'` What does it mean?

Comment: Once of those values is `nil`.  This isn't allowed, and if you want to hold a `nil` value you'll need to use `NSNull` instead.

Comment: Solved now! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Might be the case with arrayWithObjects(but not sure),because it returns an auto-released array.Use initWithObjects which returns an array you must then release to avoid a memory leak.

Check This : [iPad large NSArray - initWithObjects vs. ArrayWithObjects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155097/ipad-large-nsarray-initwithobjects-vs-arraywithobjects)